# java : how to record every action performed by looged user in my application to log file java

Tags: java

I'm working on a application where client need to keep track on every action performed by users so they can know which users made some mistake and which kind of mistake and when it does, i want to record all actions from log in until the user logged out in a log file and in database table also. Have any suggestion around this?

Comment: what about any logger library out here? you can add a log on every possible action then

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logging user actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391269/logging-user-actions)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115858/logging-user-activity-in-web-app

Comment: Then on every action write something into your log file. What is your specific problem here?

Comment: can log4j do this for me ?